# Get all config files (which created using Transformation under web.config) into VSTS CI Build Artifacts

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, configuration-files, web-config-transform, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I have a web project which has one web.config and other three web configs. web.Debug.config, web.Staging.Config and web.Release.config. I want these three config files into my VSTS CI Build Artifacts. My configs location structure in solution explorer within visual studio as below.

```
Web.config
|__Web.Debug.config
|__Web.Staging.config
|__Web.Release.config.
```

For complete my purpose I set the **Build Action** and **Copy to Output Folder** properties for these files using Visual Studio. So i tried following combinations but my VSTS CI Build Artifact is not showing these configs.

```
Build Action = Content
Copy to Output Folder = Copy If Newer
```

Above combination didn't work. Than i tried following.

```
Build Action = Content
Copy to Output Folder = Copy Always
```

But this combination also failed. Can you please let me know the right combination which keep my these three configs in VSTS CI Build artifacts.

Comment: Can you share your build pipline/defintion?

Comment: Although i can't share but if you please let me know specific point of CI/CD pipeline than I will be able to share.

Comment: Does Leo Liu-MSFT's answer helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Get all config files (which created using Transformation under web.config) into VSTS CI Build Artifacts

First, make sure those changes about `Build Action` and `Copy to Output Folder` properties are committed and synced to your Repos, use the `Copy Files` task to copy those files from build directory to Artifacts.

I have created a sample to do this, you can check the build definition for `Copy Files` task and `Publish Artifact` task:

[image]

Only copy the `\bin` folder.

[image]

The Build Artifacts result:

[image]

If above not help you, please share more detailed info about your build definition.

Hope this helps.